# getline and cin in CPP

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following piece of code in which the cin is before getline and the getline is capturing the new line hence not assigning any value to its variable; The code is

```
int main(){
    string a,b;
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    getline(cin,a);
    cout<<a;
    return 0;
}
```

PS:As soon as I press  enter after entering a No , Program ends(i..e getline captures newline and so a is null.It would be great if someone could suggest me a resource for learning basic I/O Concepts in Cpp)

Comment: I suggest reading [**Standard C++ IOStreams and Locales**](http://www.amazon.com/Standard-IOStreams-Locales-Programmers-Reference/dp/0321585585) as it's good for both novice and advanced learners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to discard the new line character you inputed before calling the next `getline` (if not, you simply read a single new line character) :

```
int main()
{
    string a,b;
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n'); // <-- Here
    // Or cin >> ws suggested by @0x499602D2
    getline(cin,a);
    cout<<a;
    return 0;
}
```

**Notes:**

- You should check the success/failure of each IO operation, including `cin >> n`.
- [en.cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io) is a good starting point as for the I/O streams documentation.

Comment: `ignore()` really isn't needed here. All he needs to do is clear the newline character, hence `std::cin >> std::ws` is all that's needed.

Comment: Thx for the comment. Whats the difference ?

Comment: Well 1: it's shorter. 2: It only clears whitespace (a newline is parsed as whitespace by default in IOStreams) while `ignore()` clears any character.

Comment: Its a matter of taste, I find `ignore` more readable (and my ignore only ignores new lines, look at the second argument, not other whitespaces). I add your suggestion.

Comment: I concede that it's a matter of taste in this context, but your example doesn't clear newlines *exclusively*. The second argument is the character at which `ignore()` will cease ignoring characters. So what the function is doing is discarding characters until it discards `max()` characters or until it finds the `'\n'` character, whichever comes first. Also, it's not `cin << ws` but `cin >> ws`.

Answer (score 4):

When you enter "No", which is not a valid integer, your `cin` stream is in an error state after the `cin >> n` expression. Therefore, no further input will work, and in particular, your `getline` will not try to read a line.

Comment: I dont think he entered "No" but a number.

Comment: @quantdev That is certainly a plausible interpretation so I upvoted your answer.